# AlertDialog.dismiss() is not synchronous

Tags: android

When I call `myAlertDialog.dismiss()`, the effect posts, asynchronously, to the UI thread.

My `dismiss()` has side-effects that my code (and tests) need to see, immediately.

But when I search for "AlertDialog dismiss synchronous," I get dozens of citations by newbs who don't know how to write event-driven code, and want their *Dialog* to synchronize, not their *dismiss()*.

So how do I call `.dismiss()` and then get the UI thread to service the post?

Comment: If i understood you correcty, you can try to make a wrapper under AlertDialog or inherit from it and then override it's dismiss() method where you can place a callback, that will be call whenever you call dismiss() method, to this callback you can put some arguments that will be usefull for your tests.

Comment: `.dismiss()` /has/ a callback - `.setOnDismissListener()`. My test control flow can't match my production control flow bc `.dismiss()` is asynchronous. If this were Windows, for example, I could dispatch the post myself with `GetMessage() DispatchMessage()`...

Comment: I fixed this by throwing away my AlertDialogs (except for the ones whose dispatch IS synchronous), and going with PopupWindow. It synchronizes